# subsop() "improper op or subscript selector" error with multiple substitutions when each individual substitution is ok

Tags: maple

I have a question about the behavior of `subsop()` in Maple.  I'm using Maple 2023, x86-64 Linux version.

The online help says that `subsop(eq1, eq2, ..., eqn, expr)` applies the "simultaneous substitutions" specified by the `eqI` arguments, so I would expect to be able to use `subsop()` to replace multiple (possibly all) of the operands in an expression simultaneously.  (For the moment, let's leave aside the question of why one would want to do this; I'll post a separate StackOverflow query on my larger problem and the sequence of steps that led me to writing code that tried to use `subsop()` this way.)

For example, Maple seems fine with this:

```
> restart;
> xyz := x*y*z;
                                 xyz := x y z

> nops(xyz);
                                       3

> subsop(1=xx, 2=yy, 3=zz, xyz);
                                   xx yy zz

>
```

However, I have discovered that for at least one test case, `subsop()` throws an "improper op or subscript selector" error on certain multiple (simultaneous) substituions, *even though each individual substitution is ok:*

```
> restart;
> expr := -(r0+Delta_r)^2*(46*r0-41*Delta_r)*r0^5;
                                      2                        5
               expr := -(r0 + Delta_r)  (46 r0 - 41 Delta_r) r0

> nops(expr);
                                       4

> op(0,expr);
                                       *

> op(expr);
                                   2                        5
                 -1, (r0 + Delta_r) , 46 r0 - 41 Delta_r, r0

> subsop(1=a,2=b,3=c,4=d, expr);
Error, improper op or subscript selector
> subsop(1=a,2=b,3=c, expr);
Error, improper op or subscript selector
>
```

I expected the two `subsop()` calls to return `a*b*c*d` and `a*b*c*r0^5` respectively (ignoring the prettyprinting of the 5th power for the moment).

My basic question is, why does `subsop()` instead throw these errors?

I have verified that each of the substitutions is individually ok:

```
> subsop(1=a, expr);
                                  2                        5
                  a (r0 + Delta_r)  (46 r0 - 41 Delta_r) r0

> subsop(2=b, expr);
                                                    5
                          -b (46 r0 - 41 Delta_r) r0

> subsop(3=c, expr);
                                           2     5
                            -(r0 + Delta_r)  c r0

> subsop(4=d, expr);
                                   2
                    -(r0 + Delta_r)  (46 r0 - 41 Delta_r) d

>
```